# GNU Sed REGEX find and alter string (no replace)

Tags: regex, sed

I have the followinf text:

```
11 Cherrywood Rise Ashford Kent TN25 4QA United Kingdom N B BONE 02/12 387
Bisham village Bisham Buckinghamshire SL7 1RR United Kingdom Neil Noakes 06/13 488
6 Kynaston Road London London N16 0EX United Kingdom MR N P SALTMARSH 04/13 907
116 Long Acre London London WC2E 9SU United Kingdom Lorna J Gradden 11/14 415
```

How can I use sed to match the dates "mm/yy" format and alter to "|mm/yy|"

Like: `11 Cherrywood Rise Ashford Kent TN25 4QA United Kingdom N B BONE|02/12|387`

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this work for you?

```
sed -r 's# ([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}) #|\1|#' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Example 1

```
cat t.txt | sed -E 's/([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})/|\1|/g'
```

11 Cherrywood Rise Ashford Kent TN25 4QA United Kingdom N B BONE (02/12) 387
Bisham village Bisham Buckinghamshire SL7 1RR United Kingdom Neil Noakes (06/13) 488
6 Kynaston Road London London N16 0EX United Kingdom MR N P SALTMARSH (04/13) 907
116 Long Acre London London WC2E 9SU United Kingdom Lorna J Gradden (11/14) 415

or

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})/|\1|/g' t.txt
```

Comment: [UUoCA](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) and the format requested was `|02/12|`